# Convert duration PT01H00M to a Period with Jodatime

Tags: java, jodatime

I've got a whole bunch of duration string I want to convert to a Period with Jodatime

I tried the ISOPeriodFormat:

```
PeriodFormatter pf = new   PeriodFormatterBuilder().append(ISOPeriodFormat.standard()).toFormatter();

Period period = pf.parsePeriod("PT01H00M");
```

But this comes back with the following error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "PT01H00M" is malformed at "01H00M"

What is the correct way for converting this string to a Period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PeriodFormatter yearsAndMonths = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
     .appendSeparator("PT")
     .appendHours()
     .appendSeparator("H")
     .appendMinutes()
     .appendSeparator("M")
     .toFormatter();
```

For this string.